# why python ProcessPoolExecutor is not using all CPU cores properly for CPU bound program?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to learn how can I use multi core system more efficiently for CPU bound program in python. For this I am running a CPU intensive program in 3 different ways to compare in my i3 processor.

1. Run in Single process
2. Run in multiple process with max_worker= 2
3. Run in multiple process with max_worker = 4

As i3 processor is having 4 cores, I was expecting 3rd scenario to run faster (near to 4x) due to using all cpu cores. but when executed, I found that 2nd scenario is executing more quickly which can only use 2 cores at a time.
Can someone please explain the possible reason why it is unable to gain advantage from each CPU?
Here is my code sample:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time, os

def cpu_bound_func():
    count = 0
    for i in range(10**9):
        count += 1

def main():
    print(f'CPU count= {os.cpu_count()}')
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(4):
        cpu_bound_func()
    print(f'Time taken with single process:{time.perf_counter()-start_time} seconds')
    for worker_count in [2,4]:
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=worker_count) as exe:
            for i in range(4):
                exe.submit(cpu_bound_func)
        print(f'Time taken with {worker_count} worker is:{time.perf_counter() - start_time}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
CPU count= 4
Time taken with single process:154.9558719380002 seconds
Time taken with 2 worker is:83.68749928699981 seconds
Time taken with 4 worker is:96.80410654699881 seconds
```

Comment: Does your CPU actually have 4 physical cores or 2 cores + hyper threading?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - my processor is Intel Core™ i3-8145U. From official website, I found that it has 2 cores and 4 threads. Your guess is correct as it is using hyperthreading. If this is the main reason, then how can I get to know physical core count using python?
os.cpu_count() does not suit with my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to use 1 process pool. The most pools, the less workers. They will all be idle, managing one core. I would also let the executor determine the max workers, just so that there are less interpretations

I would do something like this

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=worker_count) as exe:
    for i in range(4):
        exe.submit(cpu_bound_func)
```

---

### ProcessPoolExecutor Example

> [docs.python.org - example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example)
>
> ```
> with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
>     for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
>         print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))
> ```

Comment: Isn't that literally what they do already? Since the pool is scoped to the `with`, there is only ever one pool active at a time and they can get their requested number of cores.